# Powering the load while charging 3s 18650 battery with BMS balance charger PCB

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, discharge, cell-balancing

I want to charge use [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32809932707.html) battery management system (BMS) balance charging board for charging and management of a 3s 18650 battery. The load and charging port is connected in parallel with power port of the BMS board. Can I power the load while charging the batteries?

Circuit diagram:
[image]

[Datasheet of the module](http://www.mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/BMS-40A-3S_SGT.pdf)

Comment: You need to provide a data sheet for the thing you linked. There is no evidence in the words on the ali-babble page that describe it as a charger. Engineers work with data sheets. This is an engineering site.

Comment: I have added the datasheet of the module.

Answer (score 1):

(TY AG I read too fast, and thought load is on the battery rather than on the charger which is OK)

### Apologies

**Certainly, you can load the charger and reduce its capacity while charging the batteries at a lower CC rate.**

---

Previous Answer to a different understanding.

If you had the load on the battery side,  you should cut charging to the battery if it is already in CV mode as the load will prevent cut-off @ 5% to 10% of CC.

This requires that you have a separate current sense for the battery rather than from the charger to both batteries and load.

Laptops sense battery current separately from the MOBO and so do mobiles from external chargers.

Comment: You do not have a charger circuit.